# Help with Draggable Div

Tags: html

following this tuturial to make the red box draggable 
http://www.diffusedreality.com/content.html

almost got it but now it's not working... the point is to make the search box draggable after the test with the red box

http://peersource.sfrails.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try to fixy your javascript validation errors:

```
syntax error on line 16
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(, );\n

syntax error on line 52
else {\n

initialize is not defined
```

And if you you hover over your red sqaure you will get further errors:

```
mouser is not defined
mouser is not defined
mouser is not defined
mouser is not defined
…
```

I highly recommended you Firbug for Firefox which you can get here: http://getfirebug.com/

It seems you forgot an close bracket `}` on line 52.

```
   48.  function mouser(event){
   49.      if(event.offsetX || event.offsetY) {
   50.          x=event.clientX;
   51.          y=event.clientY;
   52.          else {
```

Should be:

```
   48.  function mouser(event){
   49.      if(event.offsetX || event.offsetY) {
   50.          x=event.clientX;
   51.          y=event.clientY;
   52.      }
   53.      else { …
```

Comment: ok good start... maybe i put the code for defining the mouse action in the wrong spot